# A chart gallery with viewpagerindicator and achartengine

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine, android-adapter, viewpagerindicator

I'm displaying ACE charts using the styled tabs of ViewPagerIndicator
The first displayed chart is always OK. 
But when you horizontally swipe to second page, the second chart is bad displayed. You have only a half chart

I don't know how to invalidate view or other tricks before calling ACE in order to force a full display

Any direction is appreciated

```
public class Analytics extends FragmentActivity
{
    private List<String> pages;

    FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set layout
        setContentView(R.layout.analytics);

        // set content
        pages = new ArrayList<String>();
        pages.add("history");
        pages.add("category");
        pages.add("cost");

        // set global objects
        mAdapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }

    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return AnalyticsFragment.newInstance(pages.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
        return pages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
        return pages.get(position);
        }

    }

}
```

And Fragment class with summarized code

```
public final class AnalyticsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";
    private String content;

    public static AnalyticsFragment newInstance(String mContent)
    {
        AnalyticsFragment fragment = new AnalyticsFragment();        
        fragment.content = mContent;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            content = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        Charts chart = new Charts(getActivity());
        GraphicalView v;

        if ("history".equals(content)) {
            v = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        } else {
            v = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, dataset, renderer);
        }

        layout.addView(v);        
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, content);
    }
}
```

Versions: viewpagerindicator 2.3.1, achartengine 1.0.0

a picture is worth a thousand words: 
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxbpQM-2XoKYM1NZYmRLUnY3cWs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invalidate a chart by calling:

```
mChartView.repaint();
```

You may also want to try this:

```
mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
```